# Add last 4 digits and type of card to Payment Information in admin view order

Tags: admin, orders, payment-methods, magento-2.0.7, authorize.net

After customer create order with Authorize.net, the info in Payment Information in admin view order says "Credit Card Direct Post (Authorize.net) The order was placed using USD.". 
How can I add type of card and last 4 digits to this block also?

Comment: The current implementation of Authorize.net payment method in Magento does not allow to display credit card details because it does not store any details about cards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created custom extension to achieve this

**etc/di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Authorizenet\Model\Directpost" type="MyVendor\MyModule\Model\Directpost" />
</config>
```

**Model\Directpost.php**

```
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Model;

class Directpost extends \Magento\Authorizenet\Model\Directpost
{
    protected function fillPaymentByResponse(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $payment)
    {
        parent::fillPaymentByResponse($payment);
        $response = $this->getResponse();
        $payment->setCcType($response->getXCardType());
    }
}
```

**view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="payment_additional_info">
            <block class="MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Payment" name="authorizenet_additional" template="MyVendor_MyModule::order/view/info/authorizenet_additional.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info/authorizenet_additional.phtml**

```
<p>Last 4 digits: <?php echo $block->getCcLast4(); ?></p>
<p>CC Type: <?php echo $block->getCcType(); ?></p>
<p>Total Amount: <?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency($block->getAmountPaid(),true,false); ?></p>
```

**Block/Payment.php**

```
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Block;

class Payment extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Info
{
    public function toHtml() {
        return $this->getOrder()->getPayment()->getMethod()=='authorizenet_directpost' ? parent::toHtml() : '';
    }
    public function getCcLast4()
    {
        return $this->getOrder()->getPayment()->decrypt($this->getOrder()->getPayment()->getCcLast4());
    }
    public function getAmountPaid()
    {
        return $this->getOrder()->getPayment()->getAmountPaid();
    }
    public function getCcType()
    {   
        return $this->getOrder()->getPayment()->getCcType();
    }
}
```

So I found that last digits was stored in db already, and for saving card type I needed to extend Directpost model a little. 
And then just retrieve all required data from order payment model

Comment: Very useful module, thanks! wouldn't you mind if I will put this code on github for those who dont like cut&paste?