# How to get the credit card details in Magento 2 using authorize.net method?

Tags: magento2, authorize.net, credit-card

Does **default Magento2 authorize.net payment method** save the credit card details?

If yes, then **How can we retrieve the credit card details used by authorize.net**?

If not, please suggest the best way to achieve so.

Comment: Check this link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155298/add-last-4-digits-and-type-of-card-to-payment-information-in-admin-view-order

Comment: I see only $order->getPayment()->getCcLast4(); has value as well as $order->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation(); getPayment()->getCcExpYear() or getPayment()->getCcExpMonth() are always empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Yes, you can retrieve credit card details from order.**

`$order` is of type `Magento\Sales\Model\Order`

The following methods get the credit card details:

```
$order->getPayment()->getCcExpMonth(); 
$order->getPayment()->getCcExpYear();
$order->getPayment()->getCcLast4();
```

Comment: Pardon, but where would one implement this code?

Comment: You can implement code in following event observer checkout_onepage_controller_success_action,sales_order_place_after